# Using Java Collectors and Stream to return a map with 1 key and multiple values

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, maps

I have an entity `UserId` that has both a `name` and an `email`. I need to return a map where the UserId can be mapped to either the name or email. Currently this is how it looks where we are able to obtain only the email.

```
 Map<UserId, String> userIdToEmailMap = futureList.stream()
                     .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                     .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                     .map(userProfile -> userProfile.get())
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserProfile::getUserId, UserProfile::getEmail));
```

And I need even the name to be retrieved. Is there a way I can do that without having to create another separate map and having to return a list of Maps?

This is wrong but something like this -

```
Map<UserId, String> userIdToEmailMap = futureList.stream()
                     .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                     .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                     .map(userProfile -> userProfile.get())
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserProfile::getUserId, UserProfile::getEmail, UserProfile::getName));
```

Comment: Keys in a map are supposed to be unique.

Comment: So would I need to use some other data structure to handle this case?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you actually trying to achieve? What is the goal here?

Comment: If you want to retrieve name or email by ID, why not store the `UserProfile` itself: `Collectors.toMap(UserProfile::getUserId, u -> u)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map both a `name` and an `email` to a particular Key, then you need a type that would hold references to both `name` and an `email`.

So you might consider creating a map of type `Map<UserId, UserProfile>` associating `UserProfile` with its `UserId`. Name and email would be accessible through `get().getEmail()` and `get().getName()` respectively.

```
Map<UserId, UserProfile> userIdToEmailMap = futureList.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        UserProfile::getUserId,
        Function.identity()
    ));
```

Comment: How would the output of this Map look like?

Comment: @user3927038 Not sure what do you exactly mean by saying "output". If you're asking how it would look like if you print it on the console then it's better to try it out and see for yourself, don't forget that method `toString()` should be overridden in both `UserId` and `UserProfile` classes. Note that if you need a nicely formatted well-readable string which should be printed, or stored into a file, then you've probably had taken the wrong route, `Map` is not a mean of string-formatting.

Comment: What I mean is when I'm writing a test case, for example previously with only the userID and email my test case was doing this - 


```//active users setup
        Map<UserId, String> activeUserProfileMap = new HashMap<>() {
            {
                put(USERID_MEMBER_1, USERID_MEMBER_1_EMAIL);
            }
        };

        when(pService.getEmailsAndNameOfUsers(List.of(USERID_MEMBER_1, USERID_MEMBER_2))).thenReturn(activeUserProfileMap);```


But now since I have the complete UserProfile instead of string, I'm wondering how the map would look like to re-write this test

Comment: @user3927038 Firstly, you should clarify: you need the `Map` containing names and emails for busyness logic of your service? The `Map` in the test should have identical type, you can't stub the behavior of the service with a Map which type doesn't match.